# WordPress loop php function is executing function multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress

on my WordPress front-page.php theme-page i use the WordPress Loop to show a number of Youtube Videos.  I use acf to get the Youtube-URL and create the iframe from the url with the function convertYoutube. Now when i execute the loop each item is showing 5 videos (number of posts im querying) and each video, also the videos from the other posts.  What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="video-wrapper">
            
            <?php 
            // video function
            function convertYoutube($string) {
                return preg_replace(
                    "/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i",
                    "<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2?rel=0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                    $string
                );
            }

            // args
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'video',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            );

            // query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            ?>
            <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="video">
                        <?php 
                            $title = get_the_title();
                            echo $title;
                        
                            $videoURL = get_field('video_url');
                            $videoEmbedCode = convertYoutube($videoURL); 
                            echo $videoEmbedCode;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with this code to me. Try viewing the page-source to make sure it's not a JavaScript problem with some slider/video code. Also double check what values are actually being stored and fetched in the `video_url` ACF field. I just tried it while baking in a generic Youtube URL and it showed 5 posts, each with 1 video, which leads me to think it's a front end issue, or an issue with the stored value in your ACF Field.